# pandas.DataFrame.load/save between python2 and python3: pickle protocol issues

Tags: python, pandas

I haven't figure out how to do pickle load/save's between python 2 and 3 with pandas DataFrames. There is a 'protocol' option in the pickler that I've played with unsuccessfully but I'm hoping someone has a quick idea for me to try. Here is the code to get the error:

python2.7

```
>>> import pandas; from pylab import *
>>> a = pandas.DataFrame(randn(10,10))
>>> a.save('a2')
>>> a = pandas.DataFrame.load('a2')
>>> a = pandas.DataFrame.load('a3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 30, in load
    return com.load(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/common.py", line 1107, in load
    return pickle.load(f)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
```

python3

```
>>> import pandas; from pylab import *
>>> a = pandas.DataFrame(randn(10,10))
>>> a.save('a3')
>>> a = pandas.DataFrame.load('a3')
>>> a = pandas.DataFrame.load('a2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 30, in load
    return com.load(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/common.py", line 1107, in load
    return pickle.load(f)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Maybe expecting pickle to work between python version is a bit optimistic?

Comment: I think this is to do with the [DEFAULT_PROTOCOL of pickle](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html#pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL) which is backwards *in*compatible in python 3. Not sure how to remedy this, either can set this value globally or maybe it should be made possible to pass as an argument in save/load.

Comment: Hmmm, after playing around it seems that it may by something to do with numpy. I can pickle a list from 2 to 3 using the protocal setting but not a numpy.array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. You can change the protocol of the dataframe pickle file with the following function in python3:

```
import pickle
def change_pickle_protocol(filepath,protocol=2):
    with open(filepath,'rb') as f:
        obj = pickle.load(f)
    with open(filepath,'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj,f,protocol=protocol)
```

Then you should be able to open it in python2 no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody uses [`pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) then do the following modification in source code to have the capability of pickle protocol setting:

**1)** In source file `/pandas/io/pickle.py` (before modification copy the original file as `/pandas/io/pickle.py.ori`) search for the following lines:

```
def to_pickle(obj, path):

pkl.dump(obj, f, protocol=pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Change these lines to:

```
def to_pickle(obj, path, protocol=pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL):

pkl.dump(obj, f, protocol=protocol)
```

**2)** In source file `/pandas/core/generic.py` (before modification copy the original file as `/pandas/core/generic.py.ori`) search for the following lines:

```
def to_pickle(self, path):

return to_pickle(self, path)
```

Change these lines to:

```
def to_pickle(self, path, protocol=None):

return to_pickle(self, path, protocol)
```

**3)** Restart your python kernel if it runs then save your dataframe using any [available pickle protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) (0, 1, 2, 3, 4):

```
# Python 2.x can read this
df.to_pickle('my_dataframe.pck', protocol=2)

# protocol will be the highest (4), Python 2.x can not read this
df.to_pickle('my_dataframe.pck')
```

**4)** After pandas upgrade, repeat step 1 & 2.

**5) (optional)** Ask the developers to have this capability in official releases (because your code will throw exception on any other Python environments without these changes)

Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the highest protocol available for the pickle package:

```
import pickle as pkl
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this constant is defined in pickle.py in the pickle package:"
    pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL = 2
    # 'foo.pkl' was saved in pickle protocol 4
    df = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\temp\foo.pkl")

    # 'foo_protocol_2' will be saved in pickle protocol 2 
    # and can be read in pandas with Python 2
    df.to_pickle(r"C:\temp\foo_protocol_2.pkl")
```

This is definitely not an elegant solution but it does the work without changing pandas code directly.

**UPDATE:** I found that the newer version of pandas, allow to specify the pickle version in the `.to_pickle` function: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html[1]

`DataFrame.to_pickle(path, compression='infer', protocol=4)`

Comment: Hmm didn't work for me, it didn't affect the protocol when it saved for some reason.

Comment: @Kyle, I don't know why id doesn't work, but I found that the newer version of pandas, allow to specify the pickle version int the `.to_pickle` function:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html

`
DataFrame.to_pickle(path, compression='infer', protocol=4)[source]¶
`

Comment: That's great, you should add it as a new answer, as that's the best solution in this situation I think